# Is there a JQuery plugin that keeps an element constant as you scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not talking about `position:fixed.`

As I scroll down the page, I want the element to scroll down with the page, until it passes the browser's view. When it passes the View, it should remain near the top of the page, but still visible, so the user can click it.

You see this in the Facebook advertising on the right hand column. (go to facebook to check it)

Is there a JQuery plugin that does this?

Comment: you mean menu like in face-book ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed).

Answer (score 0):

Lately been using almost all of twitters bootstrap real nice and one for you: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this ... it may help 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [this Plugin](http://www.vertstudios.com/blog/jquery-sticky-scroller-position-fixed-plugin/)

here is a [demo](http://vertstudios.com/blog/demo/stickyscroller/demo.php)

jQuery [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) is also a very good plugin which have many other features, [here](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/#) is a example of sticky nav using waypoints. :)